# Laravel 5.2 Method Not Allowed Exception on Production Server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've build a simple from in `laravel` which takes some data and stores it in the DataBase.

Problem occurred when i uploaded my code on production server.
In development and local it's working perfectly, but when i try to submit the same form on production server it throws following exception:

> **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:**

I've already checked my **form and route methods** both are post. I'm lost in it.

**routes Code**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); 
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
    Route::post('/ajax-registration','RegistrationController@registration');
    Route::post("/signup", "Api\ApplicantRegistrationController@registration");
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/roles/{id}',"HomeController@roles");
    Route::post('/complete-profile', 'HomeController@completeProfile');
});
```

**Controller Code** (the function which i am calling from route)

```
public function completeProfile(Request $request){
    If(Input::hasFile('file')){

        $file = Input::file('file');
        $cDate = date("d-m-Y_H:i:s");
        $destinationPath = public_path(). '/uploads/';
        $filename = $cDate."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    }
    $insert = DB::table('Applicant')->insert(
        [
            'name' => Auth::user()->name, 
            'email' => Auth::user()->email, 
            'total_experience' => $request->input('int_exp'), 
            'functional_area' => $request->input('txtFunctionalArea'), 
            'current_role' => $request->input('txtRole'), 
            'current_company' => $request->input('company'), 
            'desired_role' => $request->input('txtRole2'), 
            'file' => $filename
        ]);
    \DB::table('users')->where('email', Auth::user()->email)->update(['allInformationReceived' => 1]);
    if($insert){
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    else{
        return 'Some Error';
    }
}
```

**form**

```
<form id="signupform" method="POST" action="complete-profile" class="mob-pad0" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding: 20px 250px;">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 mob-pad0 padd-right60">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="int_exp">Total Experience</label>
          <select class="form-control border-radius0" name="int_exp" id="int_exp" tabindex="2" required="required">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            Dropdown Using Ajax
            <option value="15+">15+</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="txtFunctionalArea">Functional Area</label>
          <select class="form-control border-radius0" name="txtFunctionalArea" id="txtFunctionalArea" tabindex="3" required="required"> 
            <option value="">Select</option>                    
            <option value="32">IT Software- Application Programming / Maintenance </option>
            <option value="37">IT Software- Network Administration / Security     </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="txtRole2">Desired Role</label>
          <select class="form-control border-radius0" name="txtRole2" id="txtRole2" tabindex="6" required="required">
              <option value="">Select</option>  
              Dropdown Using Ajax
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 mob-pad0 padd-right60">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="company">Current Company</label>
          <input name="company" id="company" type="text" placeholder="Current Company" class="form-control border-radius0" required="required" tabindex="5"/>
        </div>            
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="txtRole">Current Role</label>
          <select class="form-control border-radius0" name="txtRole" id="txtRole" tabindex="4" required="required">
              <option value="">Select</option> 
              Dropdown Using Ajax 
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="resume">Resume (PDF/DOC)</label>
          <input type="file" name="file" id="resume" class="form-control border-radius0" required="required" accept=".pdf,.doc, .docx" onchange="validate_fileupload(this);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="csrfToken" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mob-pad0 text-center padd30">
      <input type="submit" id="submitbtn_2" value="Get Started" class="inputButton btn btn-success"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please show your routing and controller code

Comment: It is usually due to not using the correct method, GET instead of POST or the other way around!

Comment: Try and change it to any instead of get or post. To make sure you are on right track. Or post your route and form html.

Comment: Also share form which calls `/complete-profile` ?

Comment: Well, before posting it here i googled it in every way that i can and everywhere it was like get/post. Which i checked so many times in my code.  But, question is why it is happening in production server only and how can i fix it?

Comment: "But, question is why it is happening in production server only and how can i fix it?" if the development and local are windows machines and production is a linux machine it could be filenaming case sensitive problem

Comment: Can you show us the form in the view ??

Comment: @RaymondNijland both are on linux environment.

Comment: @Maraboc please check the updated question, thank you.

Comment: Try it with this : `action="{{ action('HomeController@completeProfile') }}"` !!

Comment: @Maraboc not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Guys for your inputs, i got the solution on the following URL:

[MethodNotAllowedException](https://www.dark-hamster.com/programming/laravel-error-methodnotallowedhttpexception-routecollection-php-display/)

And made two changes in my code:

one in route, changed method to any
and one in form, changed post method to PUT.